# Asynchronous messages on web page

Tags: angular

I've got an interesting problem to solve, but I'm stuck. I have a component which is displaying notifications. The notifications come one by one from an event emitter. I would like to show each notification for a specific amount of time, like 5 seconds, and then remove it.

My approach is to put each new notification in an array (displayed in the template of the component), setup a timer with Observable.timer and remove it after 5 seconds. But there will be two asynchronous access on the array with adding and deleting, so the indexes are not reliable.

Is there any way I can solve this elegantly?

Comment: Well, I can answer this mayself now. Javascript is single-threaded, asynchronous functions will be processed sequentially. There will be no concurrent access to the array.

Answer (score 0):

Is notification an Object ? If so, you can add a "time" parameter in it. Every secconds, an Observable.timer will add 1 to every "time" attribute of notification in the table. If a notif has a "time" attribute above 5, it will be deleted.

Comment: Yeah, I could add any information in that object. but the problem still exists, that there are two threads accessing that array simultaneously; the timer and the listener for new notifications. The problem with that is the keys of the array are not preserved. Checking for the time parameter and deleting the item is not an atomic operation. What if during the `.slice()` algorithm there will be added a new item?

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea, I would use a map instead of an array though, either to insert and delete elements from it. Here's a code snippet that would work for that:

```
const a = new EventEmitter<string>();
const notifications = {};
a.asObservable()
    .flatMap((n, i) => {
        notifications[i] = n;
        return Observable.timer(5000)
            .do(() => delete notifications[i]);
    })
```